# Qui n'auront / ont jamais eu la chance d'être vieux

Tags: conjugaison

Bonjour,

*Sa disparition* d'Olivia Delachanal (au début du livre) :

> À mes grands-pères, qui n'auront jamais eu la chance d'être vieux. À
> mes grands-mères, qui ont traversé un siècle la tête haute.

*qui n'**auront** jamais **eu** la chance d'être vieux* = *n'**ont** probablement jamais **eu** la chance d'être vieux*

Je ne comprends pas ce que l'auteure voulait dire.

> Le futur antérieur a d'autres emplois particuliers. Entre autres, il
> peut servir à exprimer, par rapport à un fait présent, une hypothèse
> ou une supposition qui peut expliquer ce fait. Dans cet emploi, le
> futur antérieur équivaut à un passé composé empreint d'une idée de
> possibilité.
>
> Exemples :
>
> - *Ils sont en retard; ils auront sans doute été retardés par un embouteillage.*
> - *J'aurai oublié mes clés au restaurant. Je ne les trouve plus*.

([BDL](https://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4129))

Answer (score 4):

> À mes grands-pères, qui **n'auront jamais eu** la chance d'être vieux.

Il ne s'agit pas ici d'une hypothèse, d'une supposition. Ses grands-pères sont morts trop tôt, sans avoir pu profiter de leur retraite, de leurs petits enfants, etc.

Olivia Delachanal aurait pu utiliser le passé composé en se situant dans le présent :

> À mes grands-pères, qui **n'ont pas eu** la chance d'être vieux.

Avec le futur antérieur, la phrase est plus forte. Elle prend sa référence du temps où ils étaient encore en vie et détache donc ce qui est dit du présent. L'utilisation de **jamais** accentue aussi le côté irrémédiable de la chose.

> LBU 14<sup>e</sup> édition, §888
> b) Emplois particuliers. Le futur antérieur peut concerner un
> fait passé par rapport au moment de la parole, mais qu'on envisage par rapport au moment où il sera vérifié.
> ...
> 2° Pour donner plus d'ampleur au fait en prenant un point de
> repère dans le futur.

Answer (score 2):

- qui n'auront jamais eu la chance d'être vieux
- ils auront sans doute été retardés par un embouteillage.

Ces deux cas représentent des cas d'emplois différents. Le second est un futur antérieur conjectural (hypothèse concernant évènement passé) ; le premier emploi est un emploi à titre de  récapitulatif.

- Sa vie n'aura été qu'une longue suite de déboires. (récapitulatif).

Voir [Wikipédia, futur antérieur](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futur_ant%C3%A9rieur_en_fran%C3%A7ais).

Comment: Merci. Il est bizarre que la BDL n'en parle pas...